# How to render class from different JS? ERROR: expecting a string

Tags: react-native

When I run this I get an error saying: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (built in components) or a class/function but got undefined, check the render method for LOGIN.`

I just want to display login on main screen from other JS file

This is the `LOGIN.JS` <--- Where I call in the index

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component, Image} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

var Login = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.logo}
            source={require('image!lock')} />
            <Text>HI</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
});
```

`INDEX.IOS.JS` <-- Where I am calling Login to show on page

```
import React, { Component, Image } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var Login = require('./Login');

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container} >
       <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.logins}>
        </Text> 

      <Login />
      </View>
    );        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React render function should return a View element to render.
Change this

```
var Login = React.createClass({ render: function() { return ( HI ); } });
```

to

```
 var Login = React.createClass({ 

          render: function() {
            return (  
              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                  <Text>HI</Text>
              </View>
              ); 
          } 

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same syntax for the Login.js file as the index.ios.js and declare it with ES6 Class syntax, and export it.

Also FYI it appears you are importing `Image` from React rather than React Native in both files.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.logo}
            source={require('image!lock')} />
            <Text>HI</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```